# Read and Write to McIDAS Area files in Python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I'm working with GOES data from NOAA, and need to save the result off in McIDAS Area format. Currently, I'm using the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to pack/unpack the binary data according to the byte format described in the [McIDAS Programmer's Guide](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/mcidas/doc/prog_man/2006/).

Is there something better suited for dealing with these binary formats (hopefully something that can be used with Python)?